# Error with CoreData using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Xcode for some reason I do not understand continues to give me "use of undeclared type" errors every time I use a core data entity reference... This is extremely frustrating since the consequence is the code completion no longer works. The even more absurde thing here is that the code compiles perfectly... I have no clue as to how to get it fixed. I have searched on Stack Overflow as well, and could only find another person having the same problem back in May, but no resolution...

Also, I tried to delete Xcode and all logs, but it did not help, and yes I have imported CoreData.

[This is a photo where the error comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeNvc.png)

[And this is the Entity in the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCMpv.png)

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: There's no common failure mode that causes this. If you can provide more detail, someone might be able to help, but right now your question is not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Select the file inspector of your data model and make sure the language setting unter "Code Generation" matches your language (Swift or Objective-C).